# Need a good "Katrina Horror" scenario/resources for my Pathfinder campaign

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons

**AVAST!  THAR BE SPOILERS AHEAD!**
In [my current Pathfinder campaign](http://mxyzplk.wordpress.com/session-summaries/reavers-on-the-seas-of-fate/), set in Golarion, I'm mashing up the Second Darkness Adventure Path, initially set in the seedy pirate-infested town of Riddleport, with the Freeport Trilogy, set in the seedy pirate-infested town of Freeport.

> At the end of the first chapter of SD, "Shadow in the Sky," Riddleport is inundated by a tsunami.  The AP doesn't make too much of it, it is kinda just "yes and it's all hard but they clean up and it's all better."  I would like to run an adventure in the flooded Riddleport of the aftermath, and would specifically like something horror-oriented.  So I'm looking for scenario suggestions.

The PCs are fifth level, and have a monk, a rogue, a cleric, and a ranger/druid.  They're pretty buff and not nice, they're aspiring pirates and half of them are evil.  I'm happy to use anything for Pathfinder, 3.5e, 3e, or even older editions.  I have a *lot* of everything published for 3/3.5e, 2e, and 1e including most of the run of Dungeon Magazine, so I might have it already (the difficulty being rooting through all that!), or at least be able to get it at my well stocked local FLGS.  I am kinda willing to consider PDF but I really like print better if I'm going to use it at the table.  Even especially clever inspiration from other game systems (Cthulhu, whatnot) are welcome.

In in addition to an adventure, any resources on what I'm calling "Katrina horror" would be nice; I want to have the flooded urban environment to be a substantial part of the feel of the scenario.  So you don't have to just suggest scenarios I can use straight, resources that might be helpful in running a D&D flooded-city horror adventure are welcome.

Edit: I ended up using a combination of Carrion Hill (Pathfinder module) and "The Stink" from Dungeon 105. Plus I basically reskinned all the random encounters - a "pickpocket" was a displaced person trying to swipe something, "giant roaches" were forced out by the flooding and took over a tavern, a "zealous merchant" was warning people away from his storefront with a crossbow, fearful of looters. Oh, and I exposed them all to cholera.

Comment: It gives me a sad to see this is a Pathfinder question.  I once put together a Vampire game that would start in the stadium many of the Katrina refugees were in while waiting to return to their homes.  Displaced vampires with a huge food supply, except that there are so many people watching that finding the opportunity to feed is difficult and the fact you haven't technically introduced yourself to the prince....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an old Cthulhu-esque adventure set in a small seaside town called "Last Breaths of Ashenport". It was originally published in [Dungeon#152](http://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=9723) but got a [free update](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/duad/20080729) for 4e.

The adventure deals with a cult of [Dagon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagon_%28Dungeons_%26_Dragons%29) that is about to perform its annual sacrifice of hapless visitors when the PCs stumble into the town. The PCs have to face off against cultists and several mutated creatures released by the sea.

During their stay the PCs enjoy a continuous heavy rain storm accompanied by severe winds and a completely rain-sodden ground whenever they move outside a building, which makes any sort of movement or combat outside quite challenging (not to mention that many of the monsters are *not* hindered by the weather).

While the adventure doesn't completely match your demand, I think it could at least give you some ideas where to start, including weather/terrain effects.

Comment: Ah, found it, I have that one, it's from the post-Paizo electronic-only 3.5e interregnum.  I'm glad I dl'ed it, I can't find a link to re-download anywhere.  That's good!  Hmm, it's a little too much like From Shore to Sea, the Open Design module, which I plan to use.  But it'll definitely come in useful, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Historically, up until about 1930 or so, ALL hurricanes were much more fatal and "Katrina-like".  Consider that now, RADAR gives on average a week of warning that a hurricane is coming.  [The Galveston Hurricane of 1900](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1900_Galveston_hurricane) is a good place to start your research on the nuts and bolts of pre-RADAR hurricane damage.

I know next to nothing about Pathfinder, or the world it's located in; however I'd say that you should start with the actual damage.  The winds would have blown down most of the buildings.  Any flooding would also take out a good amount of foodstuffs (or spoiled them with salt-water).

With the city partially under water, civilian authority powerless to enforce any kind of order; you now have the start of Katrina catastrophe.  All you need to do is create a handful of very hungry people who are desperate.  Once the PCs have ANYTHING (weapons, food, hope) the mob will move in to take it away from them.  I would also resort to VERY dirty tricks against the PCs.  The people in that city are hungry and dying slowly.